# Postgresql query records since 22:00 yesterday

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to build a postgres query to pull records since 22:00 the previos day. Through the research I've done, I have come up with:

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3
WHERE field2 >= CONCAT((DATE(now()::timestamp::date - '1 day'::INTERVAL)) || ' 22:00:00')
ORDER BY field2 ASC;
```

It errors on the >=

When running by itself:
`select CONCAT(DATE(now()::timestamp::date - '1 day'::INTERVAL) || ' 22:00:00')`

it produces the correct string: "2019-02-12 22:00:00"

Comment: No `FROM` clause?

Comment: A table has _columns_, not fields. (A timestamp has fields for minutes etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is:

```
where field2 >= current_date - interval '2 hour'
```

Comment: Beautiful. I like it.

Comment: Wow, I was way off. Thank you.